# QHBoxLayout widget alignment only affects first widget

Tags: c++, qt

when I create a `QHBoxLayout` and I add widgets in it with `addWidget` and then call `myLayout->setAlignment(newWidget, Qt::AlignLeft)`, this only snaps the first widget I add. When I add other widgets and set their alignment to left too, they still start off at the center of the layout and then get squeezed in the more widgets I add. How do I make them all stick to the left next to each other?

Comment: perhaps your first widget has horizontal expanding policy. If you want to stick them, try to add spacer as last layout item (using `addStretch` method). Also you'd better use `QHBoxLayout` class instead of using `QLayout` directly.

Comment: yes, sorry, I use a QHBoxLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correct, what you want is to have your widgets in a horizontal line but as left as possible?

If so you can add your QHBoxLayot to the general `this->getLayout()->addLayout(YourLayout)`and then use `setContentMargins();` or `setStretchFactor(QWidget * widget, int stretch)`

Without the code is difficult but ... Another possible problem can be the widgets size. You can fix it using `setSizePolicy(...)` with the MinimumExpanding  `setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred );`